# How does Application.genuine work?

Tags: unity

In Unity, does anyone know exactly what is behind the scenes of [Application.genuine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-genuine.html)?

More specifically, I would like to understand its exact process so I can understand:

1. If I can use it safely without "false negatives".
2. If it considers text (or other) assets stored in a Resources folder (e.g. my level config files).

Just for context, I want to say that my target platform is iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's just using a checksum over the binary to determine whether there have been any modifications. I don't think it would verify/check any external resources. Have you tried some black box testing with it?

To say for sure you'd have to look into the source code, which again might be something people with the source code license might not be allowed to reveal. You could use a disassembler to track the code, but that's probably quite a bit tedious to do.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I suspected as well. In this case, its uses are very limited... I haven't tested to see if I can make it return false yet, this will probably be my next step.